# How do I create a chat client with an input stuck to the bottom of the page, nav bar at top, and scrollable inner content pane?

Tags: css, flexbox

I've been playing around with jsfiddle, after not being able to get the design working in my project, and I'm still coming up short. I'm using Tailwind but that shouldn't matter, I can style anything I need to any way I need to.

Either I can get a scroll bar, but it's for the whole page, or I can lock the page from scrolling but the content then just overflows the bounds of the parent even though I have overflow-y set to scroll.

In pseudocode I want a page to look like this:

```
<header> #static/attached to top. No scroll bar to the side.
<body> #scrollable. Scroll bar always present.
<text input> #static/attached to bottom. No scroll bar to the side.
```

Here is the JS fiddle (https://jsfiddle.net/o6yjnmtp/2/), and the CSS is below. The elements more or less need to stay there due to templating. I do have full control over the styling of all of the elements. If looking at the JSFiddle, note that I do have the body tag set with styling as well.

```
<body class="min-w-full min-h-full h-screen flex flex-col">
  <div name="window" class="min-w-full overflow-hidden flex flex-col">
    <div class="overflow-hidden flex flex-col">
      <div id="story" class="min-w-full flex flex-col flex-1 justify-end overflow-y-scroll" phx-window-keyup="hotkey">
          # CONTENT GOES HERE
      </div>
    </div>

    <input id="prompt" type="textarea" class="min-w-full rounded-lg resize-y flex-shrink" placeholder="Enter Commands Here...">

  </div>
</body>
```

I am only concerned with getting this working in the latest Chrome browser for now. Here are the references for the above classes if more detailed info is needed.

- [min-w-full](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/min-width)
- [min-h-full](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/min-height)
- [h-screen](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/height)
- [flex](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/flex)
- [flex-col](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/flex-col)
- [flex-1](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/flex)
- [justify-end](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/justify-content)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please edit your question to add your CSS code  then someone can help you

Comment: Sorry about that. Fixed.

Comment: Your fiddle appears to be working for me.

Comment: @Terry What browser are you on? For me, I can see the text, the bottom input is locked to the bottom of the screen, and I have the space for the vertical scroll bar in the spot that should scroll. But the content overflows the inner div and disappears without an actual scroll bar appearing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

HTML

```
  <div class="flex-container">
      <div class="sticky-header">
        this is a sticky header
      </div>
      <div class="content">
        <span id="41e83ff8-2fba-49b5-a77b-bde56e2bf6f1"><span class="text-gray-700">&gt; east</span></span>
        <span id="5a7e216a-5e92-4caf-9966-6b97ff91ccff"><span class="text-gray-700">&gt; north</span></span>
        <span id="1999626e-c3df-4425-8e6b-840437402a96"><span class="text-gray-700">&gt; west</span></span>
        <span id="f219795f-78d7-43fa-a9f0-73aec6fc4913"><span class="text-gray-700">&gt; out</span></span>
        <span id="52fc761b-f09b-4091-99ce-1e43f6d6f9d2"><span class="text-gray-700">&gt; west</span></span>
        <span id="242903c4-fe4c-4f68-ba30-66bd3b8b113e"><span class="text-gray-700">&gt; north</span></span>
        <span id="cd06e6ca-eec7-4fe5-aac3-437704f8f4c6"><span class="text-gray-700">&gt; west</span></span>
        <span id="c8621689-1fe4-44e2-a032-8926905784ab"><span class="text-gray-700">&gt; east</span></span>
        <span id="cbd163a3-bc42-462e-b6b4-85939d521447"><span class="text-gray-700">&gt; west</span></span>
        <span id="a9679d11-c537-4d27-a1ec-f9411a39a1cf"><span class="text-gray-700">&gt; east</span></span>
        <span id="cc455404-66d7-45ad-a3d3-23d674ac2f95"><span class="text-gray-700">&gt; out</span></span>
        <span id="77a031f5-d963-474c-bb03-e28db208344a"><span class="text-gray-700">&gt; west</span></span>
        <span id="cb8cfe80-1fcb-4eeb-bed7-c3e7ec3996b2"><span class="text-gray-700">&gt; east</span></span>
        <span id="d5d9608b-f79e-4d47-8d20-5eae897ed6e4"><span class="text-gray-700">&gt; out</span></span>
        <span id="49825903-2a13-449b-82b3-878bd91b3628"><span class="text-gray-700">&gt; west</span></span>
        <span id="01030630-7755-4ea5-be8a-9a27e13dce49"><span class="text-gray-700">&gt; east</span></span>
        <span id="08ea7509-49dd-4478-9167-eb084ff674f4"><span class="text-gray-700">&gt; out</span></span>
        <span id="85db6407-efa5-4b9b-bad6-05fe0c154bb7"><span class="text-gray-700">&gt; west</span></span>
        <span id="404c4436-701f-4bb1-86d0-bcbfca3a33af"><span class="text-gray-700">&gt; east</span></span>
        <span id="eb184568-b8f0-414e-8e29-a8262ddf6acb"><span class="text-gray-700">&gt; out</span></span>
        <span id="a38db761-b609-4c95-9250-1f86c2dbc29b"><span class="text-gray-700">&gt; west</span></span>
        <span id="e1929b54-d924-4689-8ffd-2278171f5ff5"><span class="text-gray-700">&gt; east</span></span>
        <span id="058f3c4d-d3b4-4072-a7f1-74fe4f48870d"><span class="text-gray-700">&gt; out</span></span>
        <span id="a82032da-5a25-4028-892b-acd6afce379d"><span class="text-gray-700">&gt; west</span></span>
        <span id="179af250-b26f-4144-a385-23e3a97890c8"><span class="text-gray-700">&gt; east</span></span>
        <span id="be6daa48-08b9-45b8-89cb-c06fd78d6950"><span class="text-gray-700">&gt; out</span></span>
        <span id="540a6d9f-06e2-4532-9ce3-f52d24c722de"><span class="text-gray-700">&gt; west</span></span>
        <span id="b6ad2827-f72a-46bd-9499-6f16f934d886"><span class="text-gray-700">&gt; east</span></span>
        <span id="4009ea00-fb0c-4a97-b5df-b6ec5a89eb6e"><span class="text-gray-700">&gt; out</span></span>
        <span id="57e9c0fc-2d75-49a8-9165-4fa5258e433b"><span class="text-gray-700">&gt; west</span></span>
        <span id="16881986-3ba0-4198-b2db-f3e55cd94f13"><span class="text-gray-700">&gt; east</span></span>
        <span id="94363d68-681d-4115-afbf-6e0a2dfae828"><span class="text-gray-700">&gt; out</span></span>
        <span id="aceff966-6566-4e66-8025-78a6dd58f5ce"><span class="text-gray-700">&gt; west</span></span>
        <span id="e4acb594-8e42-4e4d-aae5-816014e585ad"><span class="text-gray-700">&gt; east</span></span>
        <span id="65b38138-cf80-49e7-b378-4d2833d3230e"><span class="text-gray-700">&gt; out</span></span>
        <span id="ce74ebe3-6743-4063-9655-af7ba7778dab"><span class="text-gray-700">&gt; west</span></span>
        <span id="af254fcb-8157-46ad-bea1-b16e531b3c78"><span class="text-gray-700">&gt; east</span></span>
        <span id="7cfba486-d961-4524-9ec4-589e9eb10d39"><span class="text-gray-700">&gt; out</span></span>
        <span id="c318e0dd-b0ea-4cc8-990e-194319d603a4"><span class="text-gray-700">&gt; west</span></span>
        <span id="c6445e53-0c5f-418c-aa4b-714f71746129"><span class="text-gray-700">&gt; east</span></span>
        <span id="f3247237-151b-45e7-8bef-6ae15695aa40"><span class="text-gray-700">&gt; out</span></span>
        <span id="ecf59372-8ae5-4a2f-80d8-82e48a984f92"><span class="text-gray-700">&gt; west</span></span>
      </div>
      <div class="sticky-footer">
        this is a sticky footer
      </div>
    </div>
```

CSS

```
.flex-container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  overflow: hidden;
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100vw;
  max-height: 100vh;
}


.sticky-header {
  height: 4rem;
}

.content {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  flex: 1;
  overflow-y: auto;
}

.sticky-footer {
  height: 4rem;
}
```

To prevent scrolling except inside our content container where we want the content to overflow, we apply the `overflow: hidden` property to the parent container. By declaring the height of our footer and header component, and applying the `flex: 1` property to the content container it will always take up all available width.

https://jsfiddle.net/3f58ga16/2/

Comment: Thank you for this. Using it I was able to figure out that not only had I been dancing around "a" correct solution for my needs, but that I'd actually configured it correctly more than once.


The ultimate culprit: 'justify-content: flex-end'


I can't tell you why, but for some reason just activating/deactivating that one CSS setting changes the behaviour from scrolling correctly to not scrolling and giving me the issue I've been having. And since I'd had that in from the beginning I just never saw it work.



That's a few hours down the drain.

Comment: Don't beat yourself up too much! Happens to literally any programmer :)